# Algorithm for optimal matching with choices and ranking

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem: there are 200 students who need to pick 4 lectures out of 7. There is no incompatibility between them. They ranked them from 1 to 7.

Is there an algorithm providing an optional assignation student-lectures? Is it implemented/available somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Optimal according to what metric?

Comment: The least students having choice 6 and 7, so a strongly convex function of the distance to their choices 1-4, is this relevant?

Comment: You think specifying the result you want might *not* be relevant?

Comment: How would you measure "the distance to their choices"?

Comment: Maybe rather the least possible number of students having a choice 6 or 7?

Comment: probably you mean optimal scheduling - this in fact is NP-Complete, probably there would be some idea for approximation algorithm but metrics would have to be defined very precise - do you want all students choose 4 lectures and just ignore all others or distribute them as equal as possible among 7 lectures?

Comment: Maybe you should come back when you actually know what you want this algorithm to do (else how can you tell if a proposal is correct or not).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods. The following one uses a maximal flow algorithm : basically you build a graph where boys connect to girl with a pipe of capacity their preference, and you maximize flow (n^3 algorithm) in your graph.

Following code does this with unique level of preference but is straightforward adaptable to different preferences

```
# each boy would accept marriage with some
# of the girl. What wedding would maximize
# happyness ?
MensN=["Brad","John","Chrid","Tom","Zack","Moe","Yim","Tim","Eric","Don"]
WomN=["Olivia","Jenny","Michelle","Kate","Jude","Sonia","Yin","Zoe","Amy","Nat"]
       # O J M K J S Y Z A N
MensP=[[ 0,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0],  # Brad
       [ 1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],  # John
       [ 0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1],  # Chris
       [ 0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],  # Tom
       [ 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],  # Zack
       [ 1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],  # Moe
       [ 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],  # Yim
       [ 0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],  # Tim
       [ 0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],  # Eric
       [ 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]]  # Don 
       
#Edmonds-Karp Algorithm for optimal matching

def max_flow(C, s, t):
 F,path=[[0]*len(C) for c in C],s!=t
 while path:
  [path,flow]=bfs(C,F,s,t)
  for u,v in path:
   F[u][v],F[v][u]=F[u][v]+flow,F[v][u]-flow
 return F,sum(F[s])

#find path by using BFS
def bfs(C,F,s,t,f=999999):
 queue,paths=[s],{s:[]}
 while queue: 
  u=queue.pop(0)
  for v in range(len(C)):
    if C[u][v]>F[u][v] and v not in paths:
     paths[v]=paths[u]+[(u,v)]
     f=min(f,C[u][v]-F[u][v])
     if v==t:  return [paths[v],f]
     queue.append(v)
 return([[],999999])    

# make a capacity graph
C=[[0]+[2]*len(MensN)+[0]*len(WomN)+[0]]+[ # Source leads to men
[0]*(1+len(MensN))+p+[0] for p in MensP]+[ # Men lead to women with respective prefs
[0]*(1+len(MensN)+len(WomN))+[2] for w in WomN]+[ # Women lead to target
[0]*(1+len(MensN))+[0]*len(WomN)+[0]]  # Target leads nowhere
[F,n]=max_flow(C,0,len(C[0])-1)
print("It is possible to do",n,"marriage(s)")
for i in enumerate(MensN):
    print (i[1]," chooses ",",".join(WomN[j] for j in range(len(WomN)) if F[1+i[0]][1+len(MensN)+j] ))
```