# Assignation optimal choices from excel file

Tags: algorithm

I am not an expert in IT or coding, but I would like something that seems to be well-known, even though I cannot find it on the web.

I have 100 students to assign to 5 different groups/topics (of 20 students each) according to their preferences. They ranked the five topics. I don't need particular optimality, just something giving a fairly reasonable assignation.

Comment: Don't overthink the problem. You can do the following: (1) Shuffle the students randomly. (2) Step through them one student at a time and assign the student to the topic that's his or her top choice. (3) If the topic is full -- all 20 students are assigned -- then use the student's second ranked choice. (4) Continue until all 100 students are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need a programming language using an algorithm such as the one mentioned in my answer here : [Algorithm for optimal matching with choices and ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035354/algorithm-for-optimal-matching-with-choices-and-ranking/69043930#69043930)

There might be excel add-ons for sale or freeware doing this.

Comment: If your answer is basically a link to another answer on this site, then it's preferable to flag the question as a duplicated. You should be able to do this by clicking on the "Flag" button below the question, and then you should get a menu that eventually lets you choose another question as a duplicate target.