# Can't find an algoritm for group matching

Tags: algorithm, matching

I need to solve a problem for school:

> In a school there are 90 students that must be divided into 3 classes.
> The children have made a classification of their four best friends.
> You have to find a distribution that maximizes the children's
> pleasure:
>
> If a child is with his best friend, he gets 20 points, 15 points for
> the 2nd friend, 10 points for the 3rd and 5 for the 4th

Could you give me some advices on how to proceed ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a constraint on the sizes of the three classes? Otherwise the obvious optimal solution is to have one class with 90 students, and two classes with 0 students each.

Comment: Yes it's a 30 max people per class ;)

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035354/algorithm-for-optimal-matching-with-choices-and-ranking/69043930#69043930